# What effect did Mariner 4 mission's findings have on depictions of sentient Martians?

Tags: history-of, mars

Science fiction used to always try to meet contemporary scientific conceptions.
Many past Sci-Fi works had speculated about [martian civilizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian) until the Mariner 4 spaceflight dispelled these speculations.

I'm curious what was the last Sci-Fi work featuring sentient martians (local life forms, not human colonists) contemporary with its main setting?

---

**Updates:**

To be clear: I'm only interested in [literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literature) works of [Sci-fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_fiction) genre, not sequels, preferably hard sci-fi, or at least sci-fi works with more or less realistic plot such as [*Stranger in a Strange Land*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land) - the latest sci-fi novel featuring sentient martians I can remember. So fantasy and alternative history genres as well as movies/games etc. are all off-topic.

---

To be even more clear: I'm trying to find (if it possible) the borderline in Mars-related science fiction, the moment when Sci-Fi writers reconciled to the fact Mars has no sentient life. I believe that this moment is within 1960s, somewhen after 1964 (the Mariner 4 mission results). However the last subject instance in Sci-Fi may have been slightly earlier.

---

I apologize to all answerers and commenters for my misleading question.
I see now that I was wrong when I allowed all-time stories. I should set upper limit for publication date. Actually I'm not interested in any story published since 1965 because it wouldn't take into account the current scientific conception according to which Mars has no life.

So I'm only looking for Sci-Fi works published **before 1965** (including 1965 - extra year is for preparing to publication).

Comment: Are alternate universes allowed?

Comment: Interesting question, but how can there ever be a final answer? The answer will change every time someone writes another story like that. By the way, what if the sentient extraterrestrial life forms on Mars are colonists from outside the solar system? Does that count?

Comment: "In 2015 there were some sentient Martians.  They went on an adventure and learned some lessons and lived happily ever after."  ... There you go, that's the latest one, until someone writes another.

Comment: @user14111 See updated question. If you can find serious sci fi work published after 1970s, I'll likely set certain timeframe.

Comment: _By the way, what if the sentient extraterrestrial life forms on Mars are colonists from outside the solar system? Does that count?_ Local forms are preferred. So extraterrestrial colonists are off-topic too

Comment: @User1008646 - Hollywood called. They want to buy the rights...

Comment: @Richard Which part of the update does make it off-topic comparing to the original post? I just constrained the genres, I haven't changed the gist. If this question is off-topic, it was off-topic **before** update and before your answer you posted.

Comment: @hindmost - There is a vastly lower barrier between "significant works of scifi" and "*any literature*" which encompasses pretty much everything. Note that my answer only focuses on films/TV where the barrier to entry is very high indeed.

Comment: asking for "the last" work is too broad. any time a new work comes out, the answers are invalidated.

Comment: You want to ask for x - when authors switched over. However, you phrase the question as y - the "last published" literature which is wrong for 2 reasons. 1) By putting a cutoff date as 1965 you have already decided that this is when authors stopped writing sentient martians. If you already know when it was - you already have the answer to questions x and y! 2) y is only a proxy of x; as has been seen by the recent media hullabaloo over water on Mars. I really don't understand your question at all. Some science fiction writers have never believed in life on Mars and some still do.

Comment: Did Mariner 4 **really** dispel the Martian speculations in a way that was scientifically more meaningful than earlier studies? People knew that "canals" weren't what was originally assumed well before then.

Answer (score 1):

- Russian children's book "[Modern Writers - for children](https://books.google.com/books?id=o-pnAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=bz_1Rc99xT&sig=oy1yHJ0hFa5ijbQm4-2sCeoK11c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimh-fs9LDJAhWIdj4KHePxCHsQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&f=false)", volume 2 (**2012**), has a SciFi children's story by Vladimir Blagov called "Martian Cats" which features sentient Mars inhabitants.
- *American Galactic*, by Laura Madeline Wiseman (**2014**) is poetry book which features sentient Martians.

Comment: The question was changed, invalidating your answer. :(